# sqlite3 Operational Error Syntax Error

Tags: python, html, sqlite, cgi

search.py

```
import cgi
import yate
import sqlite3
import sys
import os

print(yate.start_response())
connection = sqlite3.connect('users.sqlite')
cursor = connection.cursor()

form=cgi.FieldStorage(keep_blank_values=True)
table=form['tables'].value
bincard=form['bincard'].value
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM (?) where BinCard=?",(table,bincard))
pt = from_db_cursor(cursor)
pt.format = True
print(pt.get_html_string())
```

search.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stock Entry</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="coach.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <img src="images/logo-cel-transparent_0.png" width="74" height="64">
        <strong>
            <img src="images/logo-cel-transparent_0.png" alt="Cel logo" width="74" height="64" align="right">
        </strong>
            <h1 align="center">
                <strong>Central Electronics Limited</strong>
            </h1>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
             <h2 align="center">Storage Management System</h2>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p align="center">SEARCH!!</p>
            <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
            <form action="cgi-bin/search.py">
                <div align="center">
                    <strong>Table  :</strong>
                    <select name="tables">
                        <option value="OPB">OPB</option>
                        <option value="TRAN">TRAN</option>
                    </select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <strong>BinCard :</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="bincard">
                        <br>
                            <br>
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </form>
</body>
```

The error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 16:29:10] "GET /cgi-bin/search.py?tables=TRAN&bincard
=123 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 16:29:10] command: C:\Python34\python.exe -u C:\Pytho
n34\ProjectShivam\webapp\cgi-bin\search.py
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 16:29:10] b'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  F
ile "C:\\Python34\\ProjectShivam\\webapp\\cgi-bin\\search.py", line 14, in <modu
le>\r\n    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM (?) where BinCard==?",(table,bincard))\
r\nsqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error\r\n'
```

I am trying to retrieve data from either of the two tables, depending on what the user selects in search.html. But if cannot figure out the query to write because i don't know which table is selected beforehand. Help?

Comment: Note that the `WHERE` clause should use *one* `=` sign: `where BinCard=?`. Your question is otherwise a dupe.

Comment: The same error is displayed when one = sign is used.

Comment: Yes, that is what I said. See the duplicate.